# Article Alternative Layout not appearing as option

Tags: overrides, template-override

I want to create an alternative layout for an article in Joomla 2.5.16. In my template's override folder I duplicated the current template override file (default.php) and renamed to myarticle.php.
But for whatever reason, I can't see my new article.php file as an option in article manager's layout option. It still displays only the default.php.

Comment: Small advice: Please update your joomal version to 2.5.20

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the folder structure correct:

Component path:
/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php

Template path:
/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/myarticle.php

Comment: this exactly the path... but joomla can't see the alternative layout.

Answer (score 2):

I fell into the trap of putting an underscore in my override file name. This is **not** allowed (https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Module_Alternative_Layouts), and if you do it, your override will not appear.

Comment: oh man, that was vicious... Thanks for posting back your solution!